# How do I make variables (generated dynamically within a class) usable elsewhere in the program?

Tags: php, oop

I'm writing a program that reads a series of tasks from an XML file and puts them within dynamically generated "task" objects (e.g., `task1, task2, task3, task4` etc.).
Each `taskXX` object has properties (`task1->name`, for example) that are populated by data in the XML file.

My program runs through the XML file and generates a bunch of objects filled with data. However, I can't use those objects in the rest of my program.

Why is this the case? I'm pretty sure this has to do with scope but I can't seem to figure it out. Also, I'm not keen on using the `global` keyword.

Here's some of the code:

```
// -- CODE INSIDE FILE: class_todos.php -- //
class readTodos {
    public function loadAll() {
        $counter = 0;

        $xml = simplexml_load_file("todos.xml");

        foreach($xml->task as $task) {
            ${'task'.$counter} = new Task;
            $theTask = ${'task'.$counter};

            $theTask -> set('id',   $task['id']);
            $theTask -> set('name', $task->name);
            $theTask -> set('note', $task->note);
            // and so on and so on...

            counter++;
        }
    }
}

// -- CODE INSIDE FILE: class_task.php -- //
class Task {
    private $id;
    private $name;
    private $note;
    // etc. etc.

    public function set($varname,$value) {
        $this->$varname = $value;
    }
    public function get($varname) {
        return $this->$value;
    }
}

// -- CODE INSIDE FILE: index.php -- //
require_once('class_todos.php');

<ul class="todo-list">
    <?php
        echo $task0 -> get('name');
        // The above statement give the error statement: "Undefined variable: task0"
        // I know for sure that $task0 IS defined within the scope of the class "readTodos".
        // How do I make the $task0 (and upwards... e.g., task1, task2, task3, etc.)
        // available for use in the rest of my program?
    ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use classes that way. The `loadAll` method should return an array of tasks instead of creating variables. When it creates variables inside the method, it's scope is limited to that method as therefore, it's not available outside it. You should also consider making that function static.

Instead, use something like this:

```
class TodoManager {
    public static function loadAll() {
        $counter = 0;

        $xml = simplexml_load_file("todos.xml");
        $allTasks = array();

        foreach($xml->task as $task) {
            $theTask = new Task;
            $theTask->set('id',   $task['id']);
            $theTask->set('name', $task->name);
            $theTask->set('note', $task->note);
            // and so on and so on...

            // Add this todo to the array.
            $allTasks[] = $theTask;
        }

        return $allTasks;
    }
}
```

Your HTML should then do:

```
$todos = TodoManager::loadAll(); // Note, I've renamed your class to TodoManager.

// Loop through the todos.
foreach ( $todos as $todo )
{
  echo $todo->get('name');

  // Do more useful stuff.
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this really detailed answer! However, I'm not sure how `$allTasks[] = $theTask` works. Shouldn't I be doing something like `$allTasks[0] = $theTask`?

Also, what does the :: in `TodoManager::loadAll();` mean? Sorry, I'm relatively new to PHP and PHP OOP in general!

Comment: @Titus - No, you don't want to use `$allTasks[0]`. The number is the square brackets in the index. If you leave it blank, PHP will continuously increase it as you add elements to the array. The `::` is how you call the static methods of a class.

Comment: Ah, this all makes sense now. You're awesome... thanks so much for helping!

Comment: Sorry, I have one more question for you: What exactly am I putting inside the array `$allTasks`? Since they are not object references, how and what is stored in each part of the array?

Comment: @Titus - Each element of the `$allTasks` array is a `Task` object alongs with all of its properties. You can then loop through the array and use the functions from the `Task` object as in my "HTML" example above.

Comment: So the scope of the `$theTask` would be within the `$allTasks[]` array? And that is what makes it accessible elsewhere in the program?

Comment: @Titus - You don't access `$allTasks` directly. It's returned by the method. When you call `TodoManager::loadAll()` that's returning an array (which happens to be `$allTasks` in the method but the name is irrelevant). If you assign the result of `TodoManager::loadAll()` to a variable, that variable will be an array of `Task` objects. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thanks to your detailed explanations, I think I get it now! :D

Answer (score 1):

PHP is function scoped. That means that variables you declare inside a function are not visible outside the function. You are just saying `$theTask = ${'task'.$counter};` without doing anything with $theTask. You could keep an array of tasks as a class member.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables are lost when the function exits. Store the results in an array and store that array on the current object.